# MYSQL Views - mathematics percentages

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database and want to get a percentage but cannot figure it out, despite using tutorials. To keep it simple, I have one column called 'StatusCode' with 6 entries:

```
 StatusCode
 200
 200
 200
 301
 200
 505
```

All I want to do is:

1) Count the number of rows in the column - in this case it is 6. Then I want to find the % of times a specific code appears. So '200' for example. I can see her it appears 4 times, so I need to somehow say:

4/6*100=66%

I also need to trim this so it is only 2 digits.

Comment: It would be nice to see you make some effort to solve this yourself.

Comment: I have made effort. I know that this: SELECT COUNT(IF(httpstatuscode = '200',1,NULL))  FROM crawler1;  gets me the count of the '200's and I know that this gets me the count of the rows: SELECT count(httpstatuscode) FROM crawler1 I just cannot put one over the other and multiply it by 100.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say where do you want to make the calculations. If do you want that mysql query does it for you, you can do something like:

```
SELECT ROUND(count(*)/(select count(*) from `your_table_name`)*100,0) 
FROM `your_table_name` 
WHERE StatusCode=200
```

Comment: Managed to fix this for anyone else: select (select count(1) from crawler1 where httpstatuscode = 200) / count(1) * 100 

percent from crawler1